# Setting JList values with for loop

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I have an array of strings that I would like to dynamically apply as the items in a JList. The items in the array will change frequently, so the Jlist model will need to change as well. This is an example of what I have now:

```
    listAvail = new JList();
    listAvail.setBorder(
            new TitledBorder(null, "", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
    listAvail.setModel(new AbstractListModel()
    {
        String[] values = new String[] { "Feature 1", "Feature 2", "Feature 3", "Feature 4",
                "Feature 5" };

        public int getSize()
        {
            return values.length;
        }

        public Object getElementAt(int index)
        {
            return values[index];
        }
    });
    scrollPane.setViewportView(listAvail);
```

I want to replace that code with something like this:

```
    listAvail = new JList();
    listAvail.setBorder(
            new TitledBorder(null, "", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
    listAvail.setModel(new AbstractListModel()
    {

        String[] values = new String[5];

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            values[i] = "Feature" + i;
        }


        public int getSize()
        {
            return values.length;
        }

        public Object getElementAt(int index)
        {
            return values[index];
        }
    });
    scrollPane.setViewportView(listAvail);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) *"What am I doing wrong?"* What is going wrong? Pretend we are not sitting in front of your computer and are not mind readers. What did you expect to happen? What actually happened?

Comment: Hi, I'd recommend you had a look at [these tutorials](http://www.dickbaldwin.com/java/Java209.htm) (they certainly helped me out a lot when learning about these JThings. I can further teach you how to nagivate through them if you don't know how to) since I think you are misunderstanding the use of JList and what is the ListModel to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't create a custom ListModel.

You can use the `DefaultListModel`. It has methods like `add(...)` and `remove(...)` which allow you to dynamically update the data.

Comment: That's what I should have been doing all along. I really appreciate the help!